# how do i combine those rows where the left side column have similar name in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

how do i combine those rows where the left side column have similar name?
there are similar names in the name column and i wish to append them in the rows.

code:

```
name                      |  url
downloads/john joe              www.A.com
downloads/john joe/2            www.AB.com
downloads/john joe/94           www.ABC.com
downloads/john joe/94/100       www.ABCD.com
downloads/apple chew/134        www.BBC.com
```

becomes

```
name                       |  url
downloads/john joe             www.A.com, www.AB.com, www.ABC.com, www.ABCD.com
downloads/apple chew/134       www.BBC.com
```

I have tried using a loop within the name column and concat but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple ways of doing this try this

```
df['name'] = df['name'].str.split("/")[0:1].str.join("/")

df.groupby(['name'],as_index=False)['URL'].agg(list)
```

This redefined your name column, which makes it way easier to group by. Tell me if this applies to your case

Comment: doesnt work, error: AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

Comment: Reedited my code, tell me if it works now

Comment: still the same error ):

Comment: Which line is causing the error the first one or the second? Is your dataframe a pandas dataframe because if not it doesnt have an index. Which causes the error

Comment: https://ibb.co/dBRKGgH  yes it is a pandas dataframe

Comment: `df3['Full Path'] = df3['Full Path'].str.split("/")[0:1].str.join("/")

df3.groupby(['Full Path'],as_index=False)['URL'].agg(list)` doesnt seem to work